# Студия не поддерживает лямбда выражения - lambda expressions are not supported at language level '1.7'

Tags: java, android-studio, lambda

Вставил строчку с лямбда выражением, получил ошибку:

> lambda expressions are not supported at language level '1.7'

Как исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В 7 версии `Java` лямбда выражений не было. Нужно поднять версию языка до 8.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Либо просто <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> на лямбде и выбрать что-то типа `switch to java8`.